# C# System.Diagnostics.Process launch time optimisation

Tags: c#, windows, optimization, process

Is there any way to optimise C#'s System.Diagnostics.Process start?
I'm using it to start external application executable, which sends some data in 0.3 miliseconds, but the process itself launches in about 500-600 miliseconds. It's not acceptable time for me - app has about 100k iterations inside.
Is it a matter of my computer? Are there any tricks to optimise launch time of such process?

Comment: How long does the application take to load up if you just double click to open it (i'd expect the same amount of time)

Comment: You're running a process 100k times in a row? Wouldn't it be better to make it work with a stream of data or something instead? You're on Windows, processes are somewhat heavy... Why do you think it's a problem with `Process.Start` specifically? And why do you have to run the process 100k times in the first place?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with Process at all, I'm looking only for some way of speeding it up a bit. And it's not 100k in a row, app runs about 30 hours and it's 100k in total runtime, so every second matters.
Executable loads up with double click rather quickly, quicker than 500ms.

Comment: I don't understand... If you only start the application once in 30 hours, why does it matter if it takes 500ms to start?

Comment: Yeah, it's launched every 30h and it runs about 30h, there's bunch of async calls to my function and overall it's about 100k new processes launching.

Comment: with a default memory working set of 200k, times that by 100,000 = 19GB of ram alone, not to mention the poor processor dealing with 1,000,000+ threads, The speed of `Process.Start` is the last place to look for optimization good luck